# Text file formatting Issue from Raspberry pi to PC

Tags: python

I am facing issue to view a text file that has been created and written using python 2.7 with Raspbian Jessie. I am posting here a simple code. `f = open('helloworld.txt','w')
f.write("hello world \n Have a good day")
f.close()`

After running the code on raspberrypi, a text file is generated and the characters are written accordingly (a new line is added after hello world). However, when i copy the text file and open it in my PC or Laptop with Windows 7, everything is written in just a single line.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi within the scope defined in the help center. It is a general programming (or Unix vs. Windows) question.

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by end line character interpretation. Try `\r\n` instead of `\n` if You want proper line break for Windows.
Of course it's possible to display properly broken line on Windows - just use alternative software like Notepad++ that handles different line breaking styles.

For more information, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations_in_different_character_encoding_specifications

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 provides [universal new-line support](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) with text files. You might have to use mode `'U'` when opening text files for transparent (i.e. automatic) cross-platform support. See [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599936) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the note about universal new-line support in Python. The question is really about opening the Python generated text file in other applications and the `U` option for an `open()` in Python doesn't really help very much. However there is an answer to the question you linked that mentions how to change the new line character, `Python 3, use the keyword argument "newline='\n'" in open()`

Comment: The point is that it's not a proper way to create text files in Python, i.e. embed the line terminator directly in the text string. One better way is to use lists of strings instead. Of course it still doesn't make **writing** files platform-agnostic but the problem is then moved to the application **reading** the files. My understanding is that Python provides enough ways to abstract the platform on which those text files were generated. You know, you're not the first one hit by text file portability issues, someone must have implemented a Python idiom for that...